# Azure VM custom OS image ARM template deployment

Tags: image, azure, customization, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

Till now I have been using the market place Suse SLES for SAP image to create my VMs. However now I intend to use a golden OS image that contains additional software and configuration. For that I created a VM with the market place image and configured it. Then I created an image with just the OS disk [Linux image creation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/capture-image). It seems MS is going towards VM image instead of the earlier disk image. However I cannot find any way to use this VM image as part of ARM template deployment. Previously I was using the standard template as below:

```
 "osProfile": {
                "computerName": "[parameters('vmName')]",
                "adminUsername": "[parameters('vmUserName')]",
                "adminPassword": "[parameters('vmPassword')]"
            },
            "storageProfile": {
                "imageReference": {
                    "publisher": "[variables('OperatingSystemSpec').imagePublisher]",
                    "offer": "[variables('OperatingSystemSpec').imageOffer]",
                    "sku": "[variables('OperatingSystemSpec').sku]",
                    "version": "latest"
                },
                "osDisk": {
                    "name": "[concat(parameters('vmName'),'-OS')]",
                    "createOption": "FromImage",
                    "caching": "ReadWrite",
                    "managedDisk": {
                        "storageAccountType": "Premium_LRS"
                    } 
                }
```

How do I use the generalized golden image from my template?

The objective is that my golden image should be usable just like I am using the market place images otherwise there will be a big change in all ARM templates. Can I somehow publish my images just like the market place images (but as a private collection) so that it is usable like one of them?

Do I need to create a VHD image for this kind of usage? I see there are ARM template examples that are able to refer to VHDs stored in azure storage. How do I create a VHD for my Azure VM OS disk? I see examples that show how to create and upload VHDs but those are for on-prem VMs. Also do note I am using managed disks for my Azure VMs.

Any help much appreciated..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I use the generalized golden image from my template?

You can use

```
"imageReference": {
                    "id":{the image resource id}
                }
```

in the template. This ID must be of the form: 
`/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/images/{imageName}`

> Do I need to create a VHD image for this kind of usage? How do I create a VHD for my Azure VM OS disk?

It depends on you. If you want to use a VHD as an image to create other VMs with new disks, you use Sysprep to generalize the operating system contained in the file and then stop the VM. You will get the VHD uri. Refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/download-vhd) for more details.

Comment: Thanks Tony. What's the difference between these two modes of image creation? In both cases I see I am creating an image of the OS disk which is being used to create new VMs. I think MS is driving for the first option, so under what circumstance should the VHD image option be ideally used? Also in the second option it seems I have to write some program to copy the VHD to a storage location, so it can be used as an image for new deployments - is this understanding correct?

Comment: @shaswatapal In your scenario, I think the first one is more suitable. You can use the VHD as an image to create other VMs. You can also use this vhd to create vm directly.https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/201-vm-specialized-vhd-new-or-existing-vnet

Comment: @shaswatapal No, the vhd file itself is in a storage. You can get the vhd url directly.

Comment: thank you. Sorry one last question.I am struggling to understand the type of details the new VM level image contains, so that I know better what is happening when I redeploy this image, Since this image is meant to create a VM that includes all the disks under the original VM I presume this image needs to keep some kind of metadata of all the original disks that were there under the original VM? Does it keep the disk data as individual VHDs internally? Is this detail documented anywhere? It would be helpful to know structurally what is the difference between the two image formats .